# Navigation bar stopped reacting (wordpress)

Tags: html, wordpress

I'v been working on my site being mobile responsive and suddenly the navigation bar stopped working ("Countries"). I'm using NEVE theme.
could anybody help please? I'm desperate and have barely have any knowledge in HTML.

site:

www.nister.org

HTML code when inspecting the navigation bar:

```
<div class="menu-mobile-toggle item-button navbar-toggle-wrapper is-active">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" aria-label="
            Navigation Menu         ">
        <span class="nav-toggle-label">Countries</span>     <div class="bars">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </div>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Toggle Navigation</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you do before it stopped working? There doesn't seem to be a dropdown in your markup, only the button. Looks like you threw out the dropdown somehow.

Comment: I was editing the nav bar margins in the mobile preview.

Comment: Problem solved. I've rolled back to the preset settings.